# Gravação de hora errada

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Eu possuo estas 3 classes como modelo.

Objeto:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="objeto")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Objeto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13, unique = true)
    private String numero;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String sigla;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String nome;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String categoria;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "evento")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Evento> eventos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String erro;

}
```

Evento:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
public class Evento implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String tipo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer status;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlTransient
    @Column
    private LocalDate data;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name="data")
    private String dataAux;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlTransient
    @Column
    private LocalTime hora;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name="hora")
    private String horaAux;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String recebedor;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String documento;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String comentario;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String cidade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String uf;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="evento",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Destino destino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "objeto_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Objeto objeto;

}
```

E Destino:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "destino")
public class Destino implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private Integer codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String cidade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String uf;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "evento_id")
    private Evento evento;

}
```

Na classe Evento eu tenho o atributo hora que é um `LocalTime`, eu preencho este campo através deste método:

```
public static LocalTime stringToTime(String src) {
        final DateTimeFormatter fHora = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        final LocalTime hora = LocalTime.parse(src, fHora);
        return hora;
    }
```

Digamos que ficou com a hora **12:00**.

Minha classe de persistência:

```
public class ServiceBase {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tracker")
    protected EntityManager em;

public void insert(Objeto objeto) {
        this.em.persist(objeto);
    }

}
```

Até então tá ok, ao ser gravado no banco `mysql` o valor que é **12:00** grava como **15:00** como se o GMT fosse 00:00 e o nosso é -03:00. Alguém sabe o que está causando e como posso resolver ?

Comment: Acredito que seja o método usado para inicializar o `DateTimeFormatter`. Eu diria para você usar a versão do método que usa um Locale ao criar o Formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", locale)` e ver se faz do jeito que você quer.

Comment: @mutlei testei e não funcionou. Como falei antes de ir pro banco pelo debug eu vi que está com a hora certa, é quando grava mesmo que vejo errado.

Comment: Inacreditável mas mudei o .jar do mysql pra versão 5.1.45 e funcionou.

Comment: Adicione como resposta à sua pergunta, :-)

Comment: @Douglas isso tem cara de configuração do mysql server, ou do próprio servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava usando a versão 6.06 do mysql-conector. Uma vez eu havia lido sobre umas configurações extras que se havia de fazer e na época recomendaram a versão que era 5.1.44. Ao me lembrar desta situação resolvi retroceder e coloquei a versão 5.1.45 e foi batata, agora está normal.